# Viewport meta tag, affect part of the webpage

Tags: html, css, responsive, viewport

I have a situation where I want the part of the page that appears an HTML table to stay at the initial size as the desktop view, without getting affected from the viewport tag.
But I want the header and the footer to have the viewport tag, so the menu etc will change and be responsive.

Is it something like that possible? 
Because I have searched without luck :/

Answer (score 1):

No.

The viewport tag is used to declare that your page is designed to adjust to the viewport and that it shouldn't be given a fake wide viewport size that the user can zoom and pan.

It applies to the whole page.

It has no mechanism to say that you only bothered to design part of the page to work on small viewports.